# Error in (function (Xi, Y, X_1, X_2, X_s, beta, beta_s, beta_Xi, delta, : argument "X_1" is missing, with no default

Tags: r

I am writing a code to implement a bayesian model with a data augmentation approach.
So I wrote a function that allows me to calculate the posterior of the parameter of interest.

I add the posterior function:

```
log_post_xi <- function(Xi,Y,X_1,X_2,X_s,beta,beta_s,beta_Xi,delta,delta_Xi,c){ 

phi_1 <-  X_1%*%beta + X_s%*%beta_s + Xi*beta_Xi 
p<- exp(c-phi_1)/(1+exp(c-phi_1))
lik_1 <- sum(log(dbern(Y, prob = p)))
phi_2 <- X_2%*%delta + Xi*delta_Xi 
lambda<- exp(phi_2) 
lik_2 <- sum(log(dpois(0:10, lambda = lambda)))
prior <- log(dbern(Xi, prob = pxi)) 
return(lik_1 + lik_2 + prior)
}
```

And to draw the parameter Xi, I wrote a function of Metropolis-Hasting Sampler inspire from *Bayesian Survival Analysis with Data Augmentation*. This function is:

```
metrop_hastings<-function(x_0, iter=1, log_post_density,
                      proposal_dist = function(x_0, prop_sigma){ 
                        MASS::mvrnorm(1, mu = x_0, Sigma = prop_sigma )
                      }, 
                      lower=-Inf, upper=Inf, prop_sigma,
                      ... ){

for(i in 1:iter){
# draw from proposal distribution
x_star <- proposal_dist(x_0, prop_sigma)
# calculate prob of conditional posterior densities
r_num <- R.utils::doCall(log_post_density, c(list(x_star), list(...)) )
r_denom <- R.utils::doCall(log_post_density, c(list(x_0), list(...)) )
r <- exp(r_num - r_denom)
rmin<-min(r,1)
if(is.na(rmin)) browser()
# accept / reject proposal
if(rbinom(1,1,rmin)==1){ 
  x_0<-x_star
}
} res<-list(x_0 = x_0, accept_prob = rmin )
return(res)}
```

I keep in R.utils::doCall, list(...), because I want to use that function for many log_post_density which are different arguments. But when I run the code, I have this message error:

**Error in (function (Xi, Y, X_1, X_2, X_s, beta, beta_s, beta_Xi, delta,  :
argument "X_1" is missing, with no default**

I try to add a argument in the list(...) in the metropolis function (`r_num <- R.utils::doCall(log_post_density, c(list(x_star), list(Y,X_1,X_2,X_s,beta,beta_s,beta_Xi,delta,delta_Xi,c)))`), but I have another error message:

**Error in doCall.default(log_post_density, c(list(x_star), list(Y, X_1,  :
object 'beta_s' not found**

Please, can you help me to fixe this error?

Thanks !

Comment: Which function are you calling, and how?

Comment: I call the first function ''log_post_xi'' in the second function  ''metrop_hastings''. The log_post_density argument in the second function is specified as log_post_xi.

Comment: Let me say it different. What expression are you typing on the console that starts the process such that `metrop_hastings` is passed `log_post_density=log_post_xi`? I know what you named the functions. I'm trying to understand what is going to be interpreted as `...`.

Comment: I Use the function as :                                                                                         
Xi_shell[i] <- metrop_hastings(x_0 = 0,  iter= 1, log_post_density = log_post_xi, prop_sigma = matrix(.001), Xi = Xi_cur[i-1], Y=Y,  X_1= X_1, X_2= X_2, X_s= X_s, beta= as.matrix(beta_cur[i-1],nrow=5,ncol=1), beta_s= as.matrix(beta_s_cur[i-1],nrow=4,ncol=1), beta_Xi= beta_Xicur[i-1], delta= as.matrix(delta_cur[i-1],nrow=4,ncol=1), delta_Xi= delta_Xicur[i-1], c=c)$x_0